# How to compare two seperate tables based on one common field?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two tables containing the same datasets but from 2 diffrent sources. I want to compare them by the "price" field.
I want to get a combined table but showing me only the results where both IDs are the same and the prize of table B is lower then the price of table A.

Here is an example of what I want. https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTSKG.png

Is this possible in SQL or do I need to do this manually with for example python.

Comment: Add all informations as text not as link to an image

Comment: Are the different sources on different server?

Comment: BTW: What you want is called *join*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like a `join`:

```
select a.*, b.*
from a join
     b
     on a.id = b.id and b.price < a.price
```